# List elements in sortable only respond to addClass after sorting

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I setup a Sortable nested form in a Rails 4 application by modifying a bit the Railscast 147 tutorial and it all works fine. In my project, each `li` wraps a `fields_for` with the fields for a nested resource, including a checkbox. My problem is that I want to process the checkbox information depending on the position of the checkbox-containing `li`. Plus, if one of the inputs gets checked, this should also affect other fields. I wrote a jquery function for doing this (mostly through `addClass` and `removeClass`) and I put calls to this function in my sortable and in an event handler.

```
  process_components = (o) ->
    $components = $(o).find('li')
    // other stuff
    $components.removeClass("parent_component child_component")
    $components.find('input.is_child').each ->
      firstcheck = $(this).prop('checked')
      secondcheck = $(this).closest('li').next().find('input.is_child').prop('checked')
      if firstcheck is true
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('child_component')
      if firstcheck is false and secondcheck is true
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('parent_component')

$('#components-list').sortable
    axis: 'y'
    items: "> li.component"
    update: ->
      $.post($(this).data('update-url'), $(this).sortable('serialize'))
      process_components $(this)

$('#components-list').on 'click', ':checkbox', (event) ->
    process_components '#components-list'
```

My problem is that this works properly only after manually sorting the elements of the list a few times (the elements become responsive to the checkbox state only after their position in the list has changed). I looked around here and on Google but I couldn't find any clue on why this happens. Could it possibly have something to do with the differences between Jquery and Jquery UI in handling `addClass`? Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: hard to completeyly understand what problem is .... create a demo in jsfiddle.net and include steps to follow to replicate

Comment: perhaps you need to also call `process_components` on page load? Still not clear what problem is though

Comment: @charlietfl here you are [link](http://jsfiddle.net/X6N6w/4/) The fiddle works so I'm afraid it might have to do with how Rails formats the form fields. I tried to call `process_components` at page load but the result is the same: only child_component fields respond, the adjacent ones don't till I drag them around in the sortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one day I figured it out, actually the `fields_for` was the culprit. I have no idea why it happens but inspecting the various elements in the rendered page, I found that the hidden `:id` field which gets generated by Rails is NOT placed as a child of the `li` containing all the other component fields. Instead, the hidden `:id` field initially appears as a sibling of the `li` containing it and therefore, `process_components` targets the wrong element in the DOM. After dragging the different `li`s around in the sortable, the right DOM structure is established and everything works. The solution to this is thus to override the Rails defaults by specifying `f.fields_for(:components, include_id: false)` and explicitly including `<%= f.hidden_field :id %>` in the `fields_for` fields. In this way, it all works when the page is loaded.